# Where is the FAST algorithm in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, corner-detection

I'm not able to find the FAST corner detector in the Python OpenCV module,
I tried this [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhQvt.png) like described in that [link](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_fast/py_fast.html). My OpenCV version is 3.1.0.

I know that feature-description algorithms like SIFT and SURF were shifted to cv2.xfeatures2d, but the FAST algorithm is not located there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [opencv-3.1.0 documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/df/d0c/tutorial_py_fast.html#gsc.tab=0) You can run FAST in python this way:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg',0)

# Initiate FAST object with default values
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create()

# find and draw the keypoints
kp = fast.detect(img,None)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, color=(255,0,0))

# Print all default params
print "Threshold: ", fast.getInt('threshold')
print "nonmaxSuppression: ", fast.getBool('nonmaxSuppression')
print "neighborhood: ", fast.getInt('type')
print "Total Keypoints with nonmaxSuppression: ", len(kp)

cv2.imwrite('fast_true.png',img2)

# Disable nonmaxSuppression
fast.setBool('nonmaxSuppression',0)
kp = fast.detect(img,None)

print "Total Keypoints without nonmaxSuppression: ", len(kp)

img3 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, color=(255,0,0))

cv2.imwrite('fast_false.png',img3)
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me, however the solution by Yahya did.

Answer (score 15):

I think the example code in opencv-3.1.0 documentation is not updated. The provided code will not work.

Try this one:

```
    # Ref: https://github.com/jagracar/OpenCV-python-tests/blob/master/OpenCV-tutorials/featureDetection/fast.py
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg',0)

# Initiate FAST object with default values
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create(threshold=25)

# find and draw the keypoints
kp = fast.detect(img,None)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None,color=(255,0,0))

print("Threshold: ", fast.getThreshold())
print("nonmaxSuppression: ", fast.getNonmaxSuppression())
print("neighborhood: ", fast.getType())
print("Total Keypoints with nonmaxSuppression: ", len(kp))

cv2.imwrite('fast_true.png',img2)

# Disable nonmaxSuppression
fast.setNonmaxSuppression(0)
kp = fast.detect(img,None)

print "Total Keypoints without nonmaxSuppression: ", len(kp)

img3 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(255,0,0))

cv2.imwrite('fast_false.png',img3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works as the official document code is only compatible with particular version of opencv and not updated there after

```
from __future__ import print_function
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('simple.jpg',0)
img = cv2.imread(f,0)

# Initiate FAST object with default values
fast = cv2.FastFeatureDetector_create(threshold=25)

# find and draw the keypoints
kp = fast.detect(img,None)
img2 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None,color=(255,0,0))

print("Threshold: ", fast.getThreshold())
print("nonmaxSuppression: ", fast.getNonmaxSuppression())
print("neighborhood: ", fast.getType())
print("Total Keypoints with nonmaxSuppression: ", len(kp))

img2_vis = cv2.resize(img2, (1600, 1000))
cv2.imshow('fast_true',img2_vis),cv2.waitKey()

# Disable nonmaxSuppression
fast.setNonmaxSuppression(0)
kp = fast.detect(img,None)

print("Total Keypoints without nonmaxSuppression: ", len(kp))

img3 = cv2.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(255,0,0))

img3_vis = cv2.resize(img3, (1600, 1000))
cv2.imshow('fast_false',img3_vis),cv2.waitKey()
```